# Google Dataflow Templates | Python SDK | LImitations

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

Asking the community for summarizing the limitations of **Python SDK on Google DataFlow Templates**:

1. Python SDK has limitation on sources: We **don't have connectors** for *BigQuery, BigTable and Pubsub* sources that can take runtime parameters.
2. We have support for runtime parameters but its only for simple parameter substitution.
3. *NestedValueProvider* is not supported(It allows us to compute a value from another *ValueProvider* object).

Please correct me if i am wrong. Let me know if i missed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Apache Beam Python SDK documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.23.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.ReadFromBigQuery), the BigQuery read connector has support for *ValueProvider* objects, so it should be possible to use runtime parameters on BigQuery sources.

[BigTable connector](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.23.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigtableio.html) is yet to provide reading/source support and, at this moment, it's only possible to use BigTable as writing output; however, *ValueProvider* arguments are not supported yet.

The [Pub/Sub connector](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.23.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.html) supports both sources and sinks, only in streaming pipelines. Same as the BigTable connector, *ValueProvider* arguments are yet to be supported.

Regarding *NestedValueProvider*, yes, as mentioned in the [Dataflow templates documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#runtime-parameters-and-the-valueprovider-interface), the Apache Beam SDK for Python does not support *NestedValueProvider*.

You can always check the [Apache Beam release notes](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/downloads/) to keep updated about latest features or follow up related feature requests on Jira, for example, there's already an [open request for DynamicDestinations implementation for BigtableIO](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-8366), although it's for Java SDK.

Comment: Thanks @fcojavmelo lets update this answer with time.